# Append comma delimited string with other data to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I am running SQL Server 2008. in a stored procedure, I need to copy TableA to TableB by making a comma-delimted string from a subset of columns in TableA and write it along with some other data to TableB.

TableA contains 12 text columns named 'Column1' thru 'Column12'.

For each row in TableA I need a comma-separated string built from a variable range of columns defined by parameters @startCol and @endCol passed to the stored procedure. I need to copy @startCol and @endCol plus the string to another table.

TableB:
StartCol, EndCol, CommaDelim

This is what I'm trying:

```
INSERT INTO TableB SELECT @startCol as StartCol, @endCol As EndCol, 
COALESCE(???) as CommaDelim
```

I can't figure out what to pass to the COALESCE function. I'm not even sure I should be using COALESCE. I'm not averse to dynamic SQL

TableA:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3 ….  
   'A1'       'A2'        'A3'  
   'B1'       'B2'        'B3'
```

.
.
.

what I want in TableB is

```
StartCol     EndCol     CommaDelim  
    1          3         'A1,A2,A3'  
    1          3         'B1,B2,B3'
```

one record for each record in TableA

I can't get any result set - I keep getting syntax errors in the COALESCE part

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: COALESCE does not function the way you seem to think it does. It will return the first non-NULL value in the list provided to it. What you need is STRING_AGG, but that is not available to on SQL Server 2008. If you upgrade to SQL Server 2017 or later you will be able to use STRING_AGG. Until then check out this collection of alternatives... https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation

Comment: Further to the point of upgrading, SQL Server 2008 is now completely unsupported, so you'll want to upgrade sooner, rather than later.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a little over-developed, but here is a technique that does NOT require dynamic SQL

Notice I set Columns between 1 & 2, but you can set any range

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Column1] varchar(50),[Column2] varchar(50),[Column3] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A1','A2','A3')
,('B1','B2','B3')

Declare @Col1 int = 1
Declare @Col2 int = 2

Select StartCol = @Col1
      ,EndCol   = @Col2
      ,C.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply ( values (stuff((Select ',' + Value 
                                From (
                                        Select Seq   = row_number() over (order by (select null))
                                              ,Item  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                                              ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                                         Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./*') as C2(a)
                                       ) B1
                                Where Seq between @Col1 and @Col2
                                Order By Seq
                                For XML Path (''))
                             ,1,1,'')
                      )
             ) C(CommaDelim)
```

**Returns**

```
StartCol    EndCol  CommaDelim
1           2       A1,A2
1           2       B1,B2
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert them into VARCHAR datatype so that you can concatenate them.  COALESCE is picking the first null column in the list.
Example:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(Length),Column1),'')+','+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(Length),Column2),'')+','+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(Length),Column3),'')
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way so that you do not have to create dynamic sql by creating a function. You may have to modify the select statements to match your schema. You can use the function this way:

```
select dbo.getString(@startCol, @endCol)

create function getString(@startCol int, @endCol int)
returns varchar(40)
as
begin
    declare @str varchar(40) = ""
    declare @i int = @startCol

    if @endCol < @startCol
    begin
        return @str
    end

    while @i < @endCol + 1
    begin
        if @i = 1
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column1 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 2
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column2 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 3
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column3 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 4
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column4 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 5
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column5 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 6
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column6 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 7
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column7 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 8
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column8 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 9
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column9 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 10
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column10 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 11
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column11 + ","
            from TableA
        end
        if @i = 12
        begin
            select @str = @str + Column12 + ","
            from TableA
        end

        set @i = @i + 1
    end

    set @str = substring(@str, 1, len(@str) - 1)
    return @str
end
```